# Why are my error messages not showing up in my Laravel 9 or 10 app when I validate user update data with Request in Inertia JS and React JS?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, breeze, inertiajs

I'm editing data using Laravel 9 or 10, Breeze, React JS and Inertia JS, when I'm editing data and validating using Request, the data is successfully validated and returns to the edit page but the error message doesn't appear.

Here is my edited form code:

```
import Title from "@/Components/Atoms/Title";
import CancelButton from "@/Components/CancelButton";
import InputError from "@/Components/InputError";
import InputLabel from "@/Components/InputLabel";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput";
import AdminLayout from "@/Layouts/AdminLayout";
import { router, useForm } from "@inertiajs/react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export default function Edit({auth,category}) {   
    const { data, setData, processing, errors } = useForm({
        name: category.name,
        thumbnail: '',
    });
    
    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            text: 'Simpan?',
            icon: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Save',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                router.post(route('admin.category.update',category.id),{
                    _method:'PUT',
                    ...data
                })
            }
        });
    };
    
    return (
        <AdminLayout user={auth.user}>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center w-full p-6 mx-auto bg-white rounded-md shadow-md md:w-1/2">
                <Title title={`Edit Kategori : ${category.name}`}/>
                <form onSubmit={submit}>
                    <div className="mb-3 md:mb-6">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="name" value="Nama Kategori" />

                        <TextInput
                            id="name"
                            name="name"
                            value={data.name}
                            className="block w-full mt-1"
                            autoComplete="name"
                            placeholder="Nama Kategori"
                            onChange={(e) => setData('name', e.target.value)}
                        />

                        <InputError message={errors.name} className="mt-2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3 md:mb-6">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="thumbnail" value="Gambar Kategori" />
                        <img src={data.thumbnail} className="h-32 my-2"/>
                        <TextInput
                            id="thumbnail"
                            name="thumbnail"
                            type="file"
                            className="block mt-1 text-sm w-fit text-slate-500 file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:bg-violet-50 file:text-violet-700 hover:file:bg-violet-100 file:cursor-pointer"
                            autoComplete="name"
                            onChange={(e) => setData('thumbnail', e.target.files[0])}
                        />
                        <br/>
                        <small className="text-xs italic font-light text-gray-400">Kosongkan jika tidak ingin ganti thumbnail</small>

                        <InputError message={errors.thumbnail} className="mt-2" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                        <CancelButton url="admin.category.index">Batal</CancelButton>

                        <PrimaryButton className="ml-3 bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700" disabled={processing}>
                            Save
                        </PrimaryButton>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </AdminLayout>
    )
}
```

Here is my CategoryUpdate Request code:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name,' . $this->category->id,
            'thumbnail' => 'nullable|image|max:2048',
        ];
    }
```

Here is my Controller Code:

```
public function update(CategoryUpdate $request, Category $category)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
            Storage::delete(str_replace('/storage', 'public', $category->thumbnail));
            $file = $request->file('thumbnail');
            $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $webp = Image::make($file)->encode('webp', 75);
            $webpFilename = 'category/' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.webp';
            Storage::disk('public')->put($webpFilename, $webp);
            $data['thumbnail'] = Storage::url($webpFilename);
        } else {
            $data['thumbnail'] = $category->thumbnail;
        }
        $data['slug'] = Str::slug($data['name']);
        $category->update($data);
        return redirect(route('admin.category.index'))->with([
            'message' => 'Successfully updated',
            'type' => 'success',
        ]);
    }
```

When I apply a validation request in the Insert / Store data process, an error message is displayed successfully